# How to output to a virtual sink from Zoom

Tags: linux, audio, pulse-audio

I'd like to send audio to Zoom from a virtual sink monitor in pulseaudio.

I can see all the sinks/sources in my environment available in Zoom, apart from the one added via `module-null-sink`. I added it using:

```
pactl load-module module-null-sink channels=2 format=float32le
```

which matches the configuration I see on an existing Jack sink. (and I can see the Jack sink/source in Zoom) If I try to force it from the pactl interface, I get:

```
Failure: Invalid argument
```

Comment: just choose the device you want to use from within Zoom. Run qjackctl to see jack connections, or another app, such as Carla, to see connections. You can even manage the connections with those apps by dragging a "patch cord". I use Carla since qjackctl connections can get cluttered real fast. I'm not familiar with the command line way of doing the same thing.